I would like to know how to skip a specific dll when performing obfuscar obfuscation
I'm using the bunifu library.
When obfuscation is performed, you will be prompted to enter a license key.
Could you please tell me how to solve this?
I've looked through the current documentation but couldn't find a way to do it.
